# LSTM for speech accent classification

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying LSTM model on this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/speech-accent-archive

This is the model that I am working on:

```
def train_lstm_model(X_train, y_train, X_validation, y_validation, EPOCHS, batch_size=128):
    # Get row, column, and class sizes
    rows = X_train[0].shape[0]
    cols = X_train[0].shape[1]
    val_rows = X_validation[0].shape[0]
    val_cols = X_validation[0].shape[1]
    num_classes = len(y_train[0])

    input_shape = (rows, cols)
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], rows, cols)
    X_validation = X_validation.reshape(X_validation.shape[0], val_rows, val_cols)

    lstm = Sequential()
    lstm.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, input_shape=input_shape, activation='tanh'))
    lstm.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, activation='tanh'))
    lstm.add(LSTM(64, stateful=False, activation='tanh'))

    # add dropout to control for overfitting
    lstm.add(Dropout(.25))

    # squash output onto number of classes in probability space
    lstm.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    # adam = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0001)
    rmsprop = optimizers.adam(lr=0.002)
    lstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=rmsprop, metrics=["accuracy"])

    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', min_delta=.005, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    # Creates log file for graphical interpretation using TensorBoard
    tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=LOG_DIR, histogram_freq=0, batch_size=32, write_graph=True, write_grads=True,
                     write_images=True, embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None,
                     embeddings_metadata=None)
    lstm.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(X_validation,y_validation),
              callbacks=[es,tb])
    return lstm
```

And when I run it for 15 epochs, I get this loss curve for the validation data. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJYPr.jpg

And this is the accuracy on validation data. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0UcF.jpg

This is the training accuracy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WaBD.jpg
And this is the training loss: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7YNb.jpg

I've only used three classes from the dataset.

Any suggestions on what can I improve in the model?

These are the steps I followed:
1. Read wav file [only reading 90 samples per class]
2. calculate melspectrogram
3. split mel-spec into segments. [this gives around 11k samples]
3. normalize the mel-spec. 
4. feed into network.

Comment: It looks like overfitting to me.

Comment: How can I improve it?